# Give wrong array association from CSV to import into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv

I want to insert into mysql based an csv uploaded file. So, I need to convert them into insert_batch format array on codeigniter like this :

```
$data = array(
    array(
            'title' => 'My title',
            'name' => 'My Name',
            'date' => 'My date'
    ),
    array(
            'title' => 'Another title',
            'name' => 'Another Name',
            'date' => 'Another date'
    )
 );

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```

The csv looked like this (with tab delimiter), for example, just two records

```
4   A   B   C   D   E   F`  10.00   20.12   100 G   H   I   98  99  989 989 s   d   0   0           0   0   0   0
6   A   B   C   D   E   G   10.00   20.12   100 G   H   I   98  99  989 989 s   d   0   0           0   0   0   0
```

I use this library :[Csvimport](https://github.com/bradstinson/csv-import).

I am not familiar using sparks, so I just put this libary into application/libraries.

So this is my code :

```
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $config['upload_path'] = "./assets/uploads";
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload("file")) {
            echo "File cannot be uploaded";
        } else {
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
            $csv = $upload_data['full_path'];

            /*USE DOWNLOADED LIBRARY*/    

            $this->load->library('csvimport');
            $tryOne = $this->csvimport->get_array($upload_data['full_path']);

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($tryOne);

        }
    } elseif ($this->input->post('file_to_remove')) {
        $file_to_remove = $this->input->post('file_to_remove');
        unlink("./assets/uploads/" . $file_to_remove);
    } else {
        $this->listFiles();
    }
```

The result like this :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [4] => 6
        [A] => A
        [B] => B
        [C] => C
        [D] => D
        [E] => E
        [F`] => G
        [10.00] => 10.00
        [20.12] => 20.12
        [100] => 100
        [G] => G
        [H] => H
        [I] => I
        [98] => 98
        [99] => 99
        [989] => 989
        [s] => s
        [d] => d
        [0] => 0
        [] => 
    )
```

This is the problem, any solution..
Thanks for the solution,

Now I got the array like this :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => A
        [2] => B
        [3] => C
        [4] => D
        [5] => E
        [6] => F`
        [7] => 10.00
        [8] => 20.12
        [9] => 100
        [10] => G
        [11] => H
        [12] => I
        [13] => 98
        [14] => 99
        [15] => 989
        [16] => 989
        [17] => s
        [18] => d
        [19] => 0
        [20] => 0
        [21] => 
        [22] => 
        [23] => 0
        [24] => 0
        [25] => 0
        [26] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => A
        [2] => B
        [3] => C
        [4] => D
        [5] => E
        [6] => G
        [7] => 10.00
        [8] => 20.12
        [9] => 100
        [10] => G
        [11] => H
        [12] => I
        [13] => 98
        [14] => 99
        [15] => 989
        [16] => 989
        [17] => s
        [18] => d
        [19] => 0
        [20] => 0
        [21] => 
        [22] => 
        [23] => 0
        [24] => 0
        [25] => 0
        [26] => 0
    )

 )
```

This is true array but how can I change the index like this :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 4
        [PIBAJU] => A
        [JIKA] => B
        [SAJA] => C
        [BISA] => D
        [DATA] => E
        [LIMA] => F`
        [DELAPAN] => 10.00
        [SEMBILAN] => 20.12
        [SEPULU] => 100
        [SEBELAS] => G
        [DUA BELAS] => H
        [TIGABELAS] => I
        [DUNIA] => 98
        [KISAH] => 99
        [CINTA] => 989

    )

[1] => Array
    (
         so on, so on
    )
```

)

Comment: you just need to insert a header row or pre-define column names.  If you are not certain how to do that, please update your question to indicate that this is your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, with CSV parsing engines, the first set of data is reserved as table headings for your fields. That means that the first line here is acting as the mixed keys in your associative array to which the values are assigned. I would assume that if you had a third line of values here it would have the same mixed keys as the first item in the array.

I will say, though, if you are simply trying to get an array of values from a CSV you don't need to introduce a dependency since PHP has a CSV parsing engine built in. Here is your example using `fopen()` and `fgetcsv()` that will spit out an array of JUST the values (i.e. with numeric keys):

```
/* USE DOWNLOADED LIBRARY */    

// $this->load->library('csvimport');
// $tryOne = $this->csvimport->get_array();


$csv = $upload_data['full_path'];
$tryOne = array();

if( file_exists( $csv ) ){
    $file = fopen( $csv , 'r' ); // r flag is for readonly mode

    while( ( $line = fgetcsv( $file ) ) !== false ) { // if line exists

        $tryOne[] = $line; // add to array

    }

    fclose( $file );
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($tryOne);
```